# Hibernate : @SecondaryTable doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I know, `@SecondaryTable` issues were published numerous times, so, if there is the same one (I haven't found it yet), please, give me the link or an advice.

I have two tables in my database (`firstTable` and `secondTable`), two POJO Hibernate classes (`FirstTablePojo` and `SecondTablePojo`).

```
+----------+             +-----------+
|firstTable|             |secondTable|
|----------+             |-----------+
|featureId |------------>|featureId  |(secondTable's primary key)
|foo       |             |featureName|
|bar       |             +-----------+
+----------+
```

I want to show fields from both these tables in the jsp from the single list object, I decided to use `@SecondaryTable`. These two tables are connected by the `featureId` field (which is a primary key for the `secondTable`), I want the `featureName` from the `secondTable` to be shown along with fields from the `firstTable`. The `FirstTablePojo` is preceded by this annotation:

```
@SecondaryTable(name="secondTable", 
    pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="featureId", 
                                        referencedColumnName = "featureId"))
```

I added this property to the `FirstTablePojo` (with getters and setters):

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="featureId", table="secondTable")
 String featureName;
```

When with a help of `<c:forEach items="${features}" var="feature">`, I get each `${feature.foo}` (`foo` is a property that was in the `FirstTablePojo` before I used `@SecondaryTable`) and `${feature.featureName}`, I see each `foo`, but none of the `featureNames` appear. It'd be great if someone could tell me what do I miss here and why feature's names from the other table do not appear in the list of `FirstTablePojo` objects.

Comment: How do you solved your problem? I'm in the same situation...

Comment: `featureId` was the primary key in your primary table? or a foreign key to `secondTable`?

Comment: @davioooh Oh, at the same time I posted this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627102/selecting-from-two-tables-in-hibernate so they are probably about same tables.

Comment: Thank you, I think that finally i'll implement my tables as separate entities

Comment: If the key ids in both tables are same then no need to explicitly mention that, it will work by just adding @SecondaryTable(name="secondTable")

Comment: secondary tables should be used when you are _trying_ to restrict access to that obj. For example, in a DDD aggregate, where you must make sure that no inner obj are ever referenced except in reference to the aggregate root. Enforcement of aggregate boundaries is one area where secondary tables really shine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point of the `@SecondaryTable` annotation is to map the fields of a single entity to several tables, exactly as if those tables were merged into a single one.

@ManyToOne is used to map a many-to-one association betwen two entities. But you just have one. It makes no sense in this context. And @JoinColumn is used to indicate that a field is mapped to a column that constitutes a ... join column, i.e. a foreign key to another table. So it doesn't make sense either.

Just use the following mapping:

```
@Column(name="featureName", table="secondTable")
String featureName;
```

This is well explained, with an example, in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-join).

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to use `@JoinColumn` if you want to put a foreign key field, which represents an ID of another entity, into a secondary table. In this case, the correct way would be:

```
 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="another_entity_id", table="secondTable")
 AnotherEntity anotherEntity;
```