# Selecting from two tables in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

First of all I'm really sorry for asking such a basic thing, I know it can be irritating, but I want to know if I make a move in the wrong direction. Of course, I will get to the step-by-step reading of the documentation, but now all I want is to solve this problem.

I want to select values from two tables with many-to-one association (each category may suit different computers).

```
+------------+             +------------+ 
|computers   |             |categories  | 
+------------+             +------------+ 
|categoryId  |------------>|categoryId  | 
|computerId  |             |categoryName| 
|computerName|             +------------+ 
+------------+
```

Here are the automatically generated POJO classes:

```
@Table(name="computers", catalog="dbname") 
public class Computers  implements java.io.Serializable { 

    private Integer computerId; 
    private Categories categories; 
    private String computerName; 

    public Computers() { 
    } 

    public Computers(Categories categories, String computerName) { 
        this.categories = categories; 
        this.computerName = computerName; 
    } 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name="computerId", unique=true, nullable=false) 
    public Integer getComputerId() { 
        return this.computerId; 
    } 

    public void setComputerId(Integer computerId) { 
        this.computerId = computerId; 
    } 

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryId", nullable=false) 
    public Categories getCategories() { 
        return this.categories; 
    } 

    public void setCategories(Categories categories) { 
        this.categories = categories; 
    } 

    @Column(name="computerName", nullable=false) 
    public String getComputerName() { 
        return this.computerName; 
    } 

    public void setComputerName(String computerName) { 
        this.computerName = computerName; 
    } 

} 



@Entity
@Table(name="categories"
    ,catalog="dbname"
) 
public class Categories  implements java.io.Serializable { 


     private Integer categoryId; 
     private String categoryName; 
     private Set<Computers> computerss = new HashSet<Computers>(0); 
     private Set<Customers> customerss = new HashSet<Customers>(0); 

    public Categories() { 
    } 

    public Categories(String categoryName) { 
        this.categoryName = categoryName; 
    } 
    public Categories(String categoryName, Set<Computers> computerss, Set<Customers> customerss) { 
       this.categoryName = categoryName; 
       this.computerss = computerss; 
       this.customerss = customerss; 
    } 

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)        
    @Column(name="categoryId", unique=true, nullable=false) 
    public Integer getCategoryId() { 
        return this.categoryId; 
    } 

    public void setCategoryId(Integer categoryId) { 
        this.categoryId = categoryId; 
    } 

    @Column(name="categoryName", nullable=false) 
    public String getCategoryName() { 
        return this.categoryName; 
    } 

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) { 
        this.categoryName = categoryName; 
    } 
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="categories") 
    public Set<Computers> getComputerss() { 
        return this.computerss; 
    } 

    public void setComputerss(Set<Computers> computerss) { 
        this.computerss = computerss; 
    } 
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="categories") 
    public Set<Customers> getCustomerss() { 
        return this.customerss; 
    } 

    public void setCustomerses(Set<Customers> customerss) { 
        this.customerss = customerss; 
    }
```

If I select values with an HQL query `from Computers` (I put them in a list) I can see `${computer.computerName}`, but none of the `${computer.categories.categoryName}` appear. I want each `categoryName` to be selected by the id. All the categories need to be displayed along with the names. The SQL query for this task wouldn't be to hard to write, but I want to use Hibernate and I don't understand it well at the moment. I thought all I need were mappings represented in the classes. Is my simple `from Computers` wrong for such a selection? I don't get any errors that would make understanding of what I do wrong a little easier. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you change the fetch type on the `@ManyToOne` annotation from `FetchType.LAZY` to `FetchType.EAGER`? This may not be the root of your question, but that's what I ended up at in a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't wait to try this option. Too bad I will have a chance to try it only on Sunday. But I'll surely check if `FetchType.EAGER` could do the trick. Was your HQL query as simple as this one?

Comment: OneToMany instead of ManyToOne, but otherwise similar.

Comment: This is really promising, thank you. Still if it works, it would be little strange, as soon as getter was called in this code, so, I think, lazy loading should work here too. Anyway, I'll write if it works.

Comment: You need to check your data... i.e. the sql database that you're quering, what does it look like? Does it have entries in the Categories table that reference rows in the Computers table according to this mapping?

Comment: Michael, thanks, but I'm sure there are rows in that table that are referenced. I had to change mapping a little bit (one of the generated classes contained a wrong table name), I suppose the mappings should be alright.

Comment: Finally it works, thank you very much! It's such a relief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides globally configuring the fetch plan of "Computers to Categories" as EAGER using   `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` in the mapping meta-data , you can also keep this relationship as lazy and use **fetch join** in HQL to eagerly fetch the Categories for a particular use case

```
  from Computers computer join fetch computer.categories
```

Then , the Categories of the returned Computers instance will be fully initialized .

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I think it may be useful.