# Hibernate delete user and user_type instead of deleting only user

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm developing a webapp with spring and angular7. I noticed that something is happening... I have generic DAOs and generic Services to do CRUD operations.
When I do a delete of a user with X id (for example, but that happens with all entities), the user type with X id is deleted too! but that user type wasn't the user type of the user that I wanted to delete.

I wanted to delete this user:

```
User {id: 5, name: hector, pass: blabla, id_user_type: {id: 2, desc: Admin}}
```

The server deleted that user, and the user type with id 5 --> `user type{id: 5, desc: Anonymous}`

I checked "On delete set null" and "On update cascade" in phpmyadmin, and It's correctly set up.

I debugged generic delete DAO method and it's called only once.

I think that is a problem from hibernate, i should specify that only want to delete object that I specify on the method, not his children.

Generic Delete dao:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Override
    public <T> String delete(final T o) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(o);
        return "Deleted";
    }
```

Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTables;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.sun.istack.NotNull;

@Entity()
@Table(name="usuario")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name = "tipo_usuario", pkJoinColumns = { @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id") })
})
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
public class UsuarioBean {


...


@ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_usuario")
    @NotNull
    private TipoUsuarioBean id_tipo_usuario;


...

}
```

I only want to delete that user, and hibernate delete the user(id=14) row and the user_type(id=14) row:

[image]

Comment: What do you think your SecondaryTable annotation does? Did you read its documentation? Remove the whole SecondaryTables annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get why have you used secondary table annotation when you have control over the application better design would be to create separate entity and then map them using manytoone annotaion, as with secondary  table my guess is its default behaviour that operations performed in primary table are reflected in secondary table.

Comment: I think that i don't understand you, however, I did spring server following a udemy tutorial so I think that it's pretty correct. Do you know the root of the issue that I'm reporting??

Comment: Could you show me an example of what are you saying? and thanks for answer =)

Comment: Hibernate works that way, on each entity you have to specify the table which refer and foreing keys to the other entities

Comment: Please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605449/hibernate-secondarytable-doesnt-work

Comment: post that on a big answer, i think that is the good solution, very thanks you, tomorrow I will try it